# Bijection between binary strings with an even-length palindromic prefix and binary strings with a bifix

Tags: combinatorics-on-words

As Danny Rorabaugh's OEIS sequence [A262312](https://oeis.org/A262312) suggests, the number of binary words of length $n$ that begin with a even-length palindromic prefix is the same as the number of binary words of length $n$ that have a matching prefix and suffix (sometimes called a "bifix").

I'm interested in finding a bijection $$
  \phi_n\colon
  \big\{s \in \{0,1\}^n : s \text{ has an even-length palindromic prefix}\big\}
  \rightarrow
  \big\{s \in \{0,1\}^n : s \text{ has a bifix}\big\}
$$ between these sets such that the length of the longest palindromic prefix of $s$ is equal to the total length of the longest bifix of $\phi_n(s)$.

For instance, a map $\underline{1001}1 \mapsto \underline{01}1\underline{01}$ is good, because the palindromic prefix on the left has length four, which is equal to the (total) length of the bifix on the right. However, the map $\underline{00}010 \mapsto \underline{00}1\underline{00}$ is not acceptable, because the palindromic prefix on the left has length two, but the (total) length of the bifix on the right has length four.

Is there a natural way to create a length-preserving bijection like this?

Comment: Bifix words with prefix & suffix $11...11$ that also have a palindromic infix seem problematic to finding such a bijection.

Comment: @CyclotomicField, equivalently with a bifix $00 \cdots 00$ and a palindromic infix, like my second example.

Comment: Did you try $uvu \to u\tilde{u}v$?

Comment: Jean-Eric Pin's idea is seductive, but it doesn't work, for reasons explained in my paper (cited below).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bijection is discussed in my paper with Daniel Gabric, Borders, palindrome prefixes, and square prefixes, Information Processing Letters, 165 (2021), 106027.   See https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ipl.2020.106027 .

Answer (score 2):

The map that [Jeffrey Shallit refererences](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4493483/121988) in his paper with Daniel Gabric ("Borders, palindrome prefixes, and square prefixes") is based on a "perfect shuffling map". For a given word $a_1 a_2 \dots a_n$ with a "short" bifix of length $k$, the map$$
f(a_1 a_2 \dots a_n) = \begin{cases}
a_1a_na_2a_{n-1}\dots a_{\frac{n-1}{2}}a_\frac{n+3}{2}a_{\frac{n+1}{2}}, & n \text{ is odd}; \\
a_1a_na_2a_{n-1}\dots a_{\frac{n}{2}}a_{\frac{n+2}{2}}, & n \text{ is even}.\\
\end{cases}
$$

results in a word with an initial palindrome of order $k$ (length $2k$).